# Two steps user login with devise, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using devise on Rails 4.0 application, i need, after login page, to show one more page for code verification, before creating session for user. Can this be done, and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the Devise::SessionsController and inject your workflow. If you have an optional two step login, your first action checks if this is enabled, if it is, it renders your second step that posts to another action that handles the authentication for this step.

You will also probably need to implement your own Devise authentication strategy.